# How to get char from first bits per byte in uint?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I have `uint64_t` variable with some value (for example `0x700a06fffff48517`). I want to get char with the first bit of each byte in the `uint` (so from `0x700a06fffff48517` I want `0b00011110`). Is there a better way than this?

```cpp
#include <inttypes>
char getFirstBits(uint64_t x) {
    x >>= 7; // shift to put first bits to last bits in byte
    char c = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        c <<= 1;
        c |= x & 1;
        x >>= 8;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: *so from `0x700fff81` I want `0b00011110`* That'd be the bit from each nybble, not each byte.

Comment: @Eljay Oops... that was a mistake. edited :)

Comment: Shifting around signed variables (`c`) is dangerous. But seems to be okay in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a generic solution that doesn't depend on any CPU architectures

```
char getFirstBits(uint64_t x) {
    x = (ntohll(x) >> 7) & 0x0101010101010101;  // get the first bits
    return 0x8040201008040201*x >> 56;          // move them together
}
```

This is basically the [multiplication technique](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14547087/995714) where bits are moved around using a single multiplication with a magic number. The remaining bitwise operations are for removing the unnecessary bits. `ntohll` should be `htobe64` on *nix. For more details about that technique and what the magic number means read

- [How to create a byte out of 8 bool values (and vice versa)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51750902/995714)
- [What's the fastest way to pack 32 0/1 values into the bits of a single 32-bit variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26200961/995714)

You can also use SIMD to do it:

- [How to efficiently convert an 8-bit bitmap to array of 0/1 integers with x86 SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52098873/995714)
- [How to perform the inverse of _mm256_movemask_epi8 (VPMOVMSKB)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21622212/995714)

> It found `immintrin.h`, but it cannot find `_pext_u64` (it found `_pext_u32`), I guess it's because I'm on 32-bit windows. However, when I use `_pext_u32` to process both halves of uint64, it crashes with unknown instruction (seems like my processor doesn't have the instruction).

[PEXT](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pext) is a new instruction in the [BMI2 extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation_instruction_set#BMI2), so if your CPU doesn't support BMI2 then you can't use it. In 32-bit mode only the 32-bit version of PEXT is supported, that's why `_pext_u64` doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

The fastest I can think of on (recent) x86 is

```
#include <immintrin.h>

uint8_t getFirstBits(uint64_t val) {
    return _pext_u64(val, 0x8080808080808080ULL);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't test this, because my compiler doesn't have that header (I use MSVC 141), but I will mark this as accepted (because this should work from what I have found about that function).  Only thing is that I thank that it should be `0x808080...`.

Comment: I guess the metaheader immintrin.h (which includes everything else) is probably more portable.  And yes it should be 0x80 for the top bit.

Comment: It found `immintrin.h`, but it cannot find  `_pext_u64` (it found `_pext_u32`), I guess it's because I'm on 32-bit windows. However, when I use `_pext_u32` to process both halves of uint64, it crashes with unknown instruction (seems like my processor doesn't have the instruction). :|

Comment: the u64 version of the instruction only works in 64-bit mode.  You could use two _pext_u32 and shift/or them together on 32 bit.

Comment: I tried that, but it crashes on unknown instruction.

Comment: @galaxy001 pext is in the [BMI2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation_instruction_set#BMI2) extension. If your CPU doesn't support BMI2 then obviously you can't use it