# Shift masked bits to the lsb

Tags: c++, c, bitmask

When you `and` some data with a mask you get some result which is of the same size as the data/mask.
What I want to do, is to take the masked bits in the result (where there was 1 in the mask) and shift them to the right so they are next to each other and I can perform a CTZ (Count Trailing Zeroes) on them.

I didn't know how to name such a procedure so Google has failed me. The operation should preferably **not be a loop** solution, this has to be as fast operation as possible.

And here is an incredible image made in MS Paint.
[image]

Comment: You need a loop if mask is not constant

Comment: Mask is constant but there are 512 of them so.. not really "constant".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This operation is known as [compress right](http://programming.sirrida.de/bit_perm.html#c_e). It is implemented as part of [BMI2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#BMI2_.28Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Set_2.29) as the `PEXT` instruction, in Intel processors as of Haswell.

Unfortunately, without hardware support is it a quite annoying operation. Of course there is an obvious solution, just moving the bits one by one in a loop, here is the one given by Hackers Delight:

```
unsigned compress(unsigned x, unsigned m) {
   unsigned r, s, b;    // Result, shift, mask bit. 

   r = 0; 
   s = 0; 
   do {
      b = m & 1; 
      r = r | ((x & b) << s); 
      s = s + b; 
      x = x >> 1; 
      m = m >> 1; 
   } while (m != 0); 
   return r; 
}
```

But there is an other way, also given by Hackers Delight, which does less looping (number of iteration logarithmic in the number of bits) but more per iteration:

```
unsigned compress(unsigned x, unsigned m) {
   unsigned mk, mp, mv, t; 
   int i; 

   x = x & m;           // Clear irrelevant bits. 
   mk = ~m << 1;        // We will count 0's to right. 

   for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      mp = mk ^ (mk << 1);             // Parallel prefix. 
      mp = mp ^ (mp << 2); 
      mp = mp ^ (mp << 4); 
      mp = mp ^ (mp << 8); 
      mp = mp ^ (mp << 16); 
      mv = mp & m;                     // Bits to move. 
      m = m ^ mv | (mv >> (1 << i));   // Compress m. 
      t = x & mv; 
      x = x ^ t | (t >> (1 << i));     // Compress x. 
      mk = mk & ~mp; 
   } 
   return x; 
}
```

Notice that a lot of the values there depend only on `m`. Since you only have 512 different masks, you could precompute those and simplify the code to something like this (not tested)

```
unsigned compress(unsigned x, int maskindex) {
   unsigned t; 
   int i; 

   x = x & masks[maskindex][0];

   for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      t = x & masks[maskindex][i + 1]; 
      x = x ^ t | (t >> (1 << i));
   } 
   return x; 
}
```

Of course all of these can be turned into "not a loop" by unrolling, the second and third ways are probably more suitable for that. That's a bit of cheat however.

Comment: It turns out that my problem demands bits being compressed from higher to lower half the time. So, higher bit gets packet on lowest slot and down from there. Is there a version of this algorithm that can do that? Reversing the data and the mask would achieve that but I think that is too costly operation.

Comment: @cen you can do that extract/flip with a butterfly network and a mask, explained somewhere else on that first link I gave in the answer. Perhaps it is easier to just reverse+extract though, reversing isn't too disastrous, for example see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9144870/555045

Comment: if the result is to be reversed then probably my proposed way is better without hardware support. [Bit twiddling hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseByteWith64Bits) also use multiplication like this to reverse bits in a byte

Answer (score 2):

You can use the pack-by-multiplication technique similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14547087/995714). This way you don't need any loop and can mix the bits in any order.

For example with the mask `0b10101001 == 0xA9` like above and 8-bit data `abcdefgh` (with a-h is the 8 bits) you can use the below expression to get `0000aceh`

```
uint8_t compress_maskA9(uint8_t x)
{
    const uint8_t mask1 = 0xA9 & 0xF0;
    const uint8_t mask2 = 0xA9 & 0x0F;
    return (((x & mask1)*0x03000000 >> 28) & 0x0C) | ((x & mask2)*0x50000000 >> 30);
}
```

In this specific case there are some overlaps of the 4 bits while adding (which incur unexpected carry) during the multiplication step, so I've split them into 2 parts, the first one extracts bit a and c, then e and h will be extracted in the latter part. There are other ways to split the bits as well, like a & h then c & e. You can see the results compared to Harold's function [live on ideone](http://ideone.com/bud3dI)

An alternate way with only **one multiplication**

```
const uint32_t X = (x << 8) | x;
return (X & 0x8821)*0x12050000 >> 28;
```

I got this by duplicating the bits so that they're spaced out farther, leaving enough space to avoid the carry. This is often better than splitting into 2 multiplications

---

If you want the result's bits reversed (i.e. `heca0000`) you can easily change the magic numbers accordingly

```
// result: he00 | 00ca;
return (((x & 0x09)*0x88000000 >> 28) & 0x0C) | (((x & 0xA0)*0x04800000) >> 30);
```

or you can also extract the 3 bits e, c and a at the same time, leaving h separately (as I mentioned above, there are often multiple solutions) and you need only one multiplication

```
return ((x & 0xA8)*0x12400000 >> 29) | (x & 0x01) << 3; // result: 0eca | h000
```

But there might be a better alternative like the above second snippet

```
const uint32_t X = (x << 8) | x;
return (X & 0x2881)*0x80290000 >> 28
```

Correctness check: http://ideone.com/PYUkty

For a larger number of masks you can ***precompute*** the magic numbers correspond to those masks and store them in an array so that you can look them up immediately for use. I calculated those mask by hand but you can [do that automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14551792/995714)

---

## Explanation

We have `abcdefgh & mask1 = a0c00000`. Multiply it with `magic1`

```
    ........................a0c00000
 ×  00000011000000000000000000000000 (magic1 = 0x03000000)
    ────────────────────────────────
    a0c00000........................
 + a0c00000......................... (the leading "a" bit is outside int's range
    ────────────────────────────────  so it'll be truncated)
r1 = acc.............................

=> (r1 >> 28) & 0x0C = 0000ac00
```

Similarly we multiply `abcdefgh & mask2 = 0000e00h` with `magic2`

```
  ........................0000e00h
× 01010000000000000000000000000000 (magic2 = 0x50000000)
  ────────────────────────────────
  e00h............................
+ 0h..............................
  ────────────────────────────────
r2 = eh..............................

=> (r2 >> 30) = 000000eh
```

Combine them together we have the expected result

```
((r1 >> 28) & 0x0C) | (r2 >> 30) = 0000aceh
```

And here's the demo for the second snippet

```
                  abcdefghabcdefgh
&                 1000100000100001 (0x8821)
  ────────────────────────────────
                  a000e00000c0000h
× 00010010000001010000000000000000 (0x12050000)
  ────────────────────────────────
  000h
  00e00000c0000h
+ 0c0000h
  a000e00000c0000h
  ────────────────────────────────
= acehe0h0c0c00h0h
& 11110000000000000000000000000000
  ────────────────────────────────
= aceh
```

For the reversed order case:

```
                  abcdefghabcdefgh
&                 0010100010000001 (0x2881)
  ────────────────────────────────
                  00c0e000a000000h
x 10000000001010010000000000000000 (0x80290000)
  ────────────────────────────────
  000a000000h
  00c0e000a000000h
+ 0e000a000000h
  h
  ────────────────────────────────
  hecaea00a0h0h00h
& 11110000000000000000000000000000
  ────────────────────────────────
= heca
```

## Related:

- [How to create a byte out of 8 bool values (and vice versa)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8461126/995714)
- [Redistribute least significant bits from a 4-byte array to a nibble](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8802893/995714)

Comment: How do you calculate the multipliers?

Comment: @harold I just write the binary multiplication out and turn on the bit in the magic number where I want to shift the multiplicand to. For example to shift the least significant bit to bit 28 I turn bit 28 to 1. Here is a correction check with your function http://ideone.com/bud3dI

Comment: I explained this technique in some other questions (http://stackoverflow.com/a/23875535/995714 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/26201755/995714) which may be easier to understand