# Fastest way to unpack 32 bits to a 32 byte SIMD vector

Tags: x86, simd, avx, bitmask, avx2

Having 32 bits stored in a `uint32_t` in memory, what's the fastest way to unpack each bit to a separate byte element of an AVX register?  The bits can be in any position within their respective byte.

Edit: to clarify, I mean bit 0 goes to byte 0, bit 1 to byte 1. Obviously all other bits within the byte on zero. Best I could at the moment is 2 `PSHUFB` and having a mask register for each position.

If the `uint32_t` is a bitmap, then the corresponding vector elements should be 0 or non-0.  (i.e. so we could get a vector mask with a `vpcmpeqb` against a vector of all-zero).

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/283382

Comment: What language are you using?  Is there some approach that you have tried that is too slow?

Comment: C with Intel intrinsics. I tried the obvious approaches: broadcast the u32, then either variable shift or multiplication to shift each u32. But it starts to get complicated and would need several registers for mask. Then merge. I think I saw something similar a couple of years ago, in some assembly for video codecs or something.

Comment: Broadast first. With AVX2 then use _mm256_and_si256. With AVX you need to split the lanes, do _mm_and_si128 twice, then join high and low.

Comment: @alecco, I posted an answer to do this with AVX.  It would be a bit simpler with AVX2.

Comment: AVX512BW: `VPMOVM2B ymm1, k1`: sets each byte of `ymm1` to 0 or -1, according to the corresponding bit in `k1`.  If the mask wasn't already in a mask register, then you also need a `KMOVD k1, k2/m32` or `KMOVD k1, r32`.  Obviously you can do this with 64bit masks into 512b zmm registers, too.

Comment: AVX2 duplicate (with the same answer which looks optimal): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622212/how-to-perform-the-inverse-of-mm256-movemask-epi8-vpmovmskb.  Maybe leaving this open for the 128b AVX version.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To "broadcast" the 32 bits of a 32-bit integer `x` to 32 bytes of a 256-bit YMM register `z` or 16 bytes of a two 128-bit XMM registers `z_low` and `z_high` you can do the following.

With AVX2:

```
__m256i y = _mm256_set1_epi32(x);
__m256i z = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(y,mask1);
z = _mm256_and_si256(z,mask2);
```

Without AVX2 it's best to do this with SSE:

```
__m128i y = _mm_set1_epi32(x);      
__m128i z_low  = _mm_shuffle_epi8(y,mask_low);
__m128i z_high = _mm_shuffle_epi8(y,mask_high); 
z_low  = _mm_and_si128(z_low ,mask2);
z_high = _mm_and_si128(z_high,mask2);
```

The masks and a working example are shown below.  If you plan to do this several times you should probably 
define the masks outside of the main loop.

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 0x87654321;

    static const char mask1a[32] = {
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01,
        0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01,
        0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02,
        0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02,
        0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03,
        0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03
    };

    static const char mask2a[32] = {
        0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08,
        0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80,
        0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08,
        0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80,
        0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08,
        0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80,
        0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08,
        0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80,
    };

char out[32];

#if defined ( __AVX2__ )
    __m256i mask2 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)mask2a);
    __m256i mask1  = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)mask1a);

    __m256i y =    _mm256_set1_epi32(x);
    __m256i z =    _mm256_shuffle_epi8(y,mask1);
    z = _mm256_and_si256(z,mask2);

    _mm256_storeu_si256((__m256i*)out,z);

#else
    __m128i mask2 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)mask2a);
    __m128i mask_low  = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&mask1a[ 0]);
    __m128i mask_high = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&mask1a[16]);    

    __m128i y = _mm_set1_epi32(x); 
    __m128i z_low  = _mm_shuffle_epi8(y,mask_low);
    __m128i z_high = _mm_shuffle_epi8(y,mask_high);
    z_low  = _mm_and_si128(z_low,mask2);
    z_high = _mm_and_si128(z_high,mask2);

    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&out[ 0],z_low);
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&out[16],z_high);
#endif
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {        
            printf("%x ", out[4*i+j]);
        }printf("\n");
    } printf("\n");
}
```

---

### To get 0 or -1 in each vector element:

It takes one extra step `_mm256_cmpeq_epi8` against all-zeros.  Any non-zero turns into 0, and zero turns into -1.  If we don't want this inversion, use `andnot` instead of `and`.  It inverts its first operand.

```
__m256i expand_bits_to_bytes(uint32_t x)
{
    __m256i xbcast = _mm256_set1_epi32(x);    // we only use the low 32bits of each lane, but this is fine with AVX2

    // Each byte gets the source byte containing the corresponding bit
    __m256i shufmask = _mm256_set_epi64x(
        0x0303030303030303, 0x0202020202020202,
        0x0101010101010101, 0x0000000000000000);
    __m256i shuf  = _mm256_shuffle_epi8(xbcast, shufmask);

    __m256i andmask  = _mm256_set1_epi64x(0x8040201008040201);  // every 8 bits -> 8 bytes, pattern repeats.
    __m256i isolated_inverted = _mm256_andnot_si256(shuf, andmask);

    // this is the extra step: compare each byte == 0 to produce 0 or -1
    return _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(isolated_inverted, _mm256_setzero_si256());
     // alternative: compare against the AND mask to get 0 or -1,
     // avoiding the need for a vector zero constant.
}
```

See it on the [Godbolt Compiler Explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g6,options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-O3+-Wall+-fverbose-asm+-march%3Dhaswell',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4QFt3gC4CdwB0AFgHwBQoksiqAztnCAPbHmXTzIr2NjatkKIAGaJhSAPoSAggDUAGgCYpZAPSqkABiRNcSALQBGJOCQIAhhCJIARgE9sCMlPSKArADYQZgB4AHczA4CRsQbFoJbCYQhwRaAAoYHABmZWwkHwBKMgBvMiQCyQlXT28fGwhzeiQAXklMdw8JWgRsQwkEPxBU%2BKyAbkKkdSQAd2QmMCg7JBgWpGwiZCgmEaRU0PCdcQsrJChAhAAaWxh0hZBaE0vhcGQRsOs5JUFB4YBRS2t7RyQAc1bLgtkLQmDBcBBkN9kBAJthzOBwL95oskDDcLg4n4JrwkRt8oUXI1vLQiDBhOgqgBrWr1EpNFrYDpdDwAFh88XxgwKmh8mmSfIF/KFguOPM0inFkol0qlh05XLFhk0SpVyrVKtFvM02p1ur1mT68sJpSQJLJBTqxTpzVJwmEUAQTJAAA5ehUqthjmbyVSDS9CsNaY1mq12p0QKz2TznZoAOQsuMS2NK2OaZ2plmpxSpwyZArDADqDyQAGEANRlwws45jVGBJAUynIMIN3TIDHmODmGwOghG4pEpCBOAU2jUmlW4MMsPMtnxaOaBMSpVpxeS3MDIYaBAANwQuGmztsYUu%2BhISCPUNoxwC2EcuDASAxfgs4T7g2NXiuTH2jmC4D3XA/wnBpPAkYcwCYRlaBARp4m9Y5h1HSk/XlYZzkuC5kWQBAfDwcxTUcPwAC5USYdAAgxMxPlsWJajqbQoiQPxcCYOAYAhLQdD0Ix5QxbAwUfScwIgCiEAARydV0Lh/cw/wkAD9z/Y5hPpVoAC992iGC4MyP0AF8KAQIIREEYZtF0JBILAfRNNYkxHx2L46PgxEHWPdIGWyT9vBgMAAggSkQhPSJoivRIUjSDI8zyV5VBwDIaWjAB2Dw3BZVJDENNCNF%2BCAICQOAmDiMBY3SX4YHMXBAkcZAgTme4oCgWxkHMKAQF%2BMAEDgGsHlBTzyNaIhET2EAmyHdrOqqeJUmyOLCLkkACphMBqiKuIh3SB0PUIpg/D%2BfKkGEVj0F2/AwCRFtYR0IEFsCodhHvPYmE7EbjvIocyNWuE%2BHlehFuWiZqisKqGypQxzAAbVSABdGlYq5bktU1bUUc0NG5URpHUa0ZHcZxsV0flQZFRRwwyYp4nClJ/HydpymsfxxQUeZpmWcxrGxVZrn2bZqnseSFHBfx4WxUF/mRaFqXJflfTssGf7sCWr7gaIUHkMUKHYfhiWaZ5/Hq3x50OcRnklU1CVNQTTUYxNhVeTp/WxUNsVjd1nxzdxy3cet3Hbfd5VeedlG3cZs30a9iOeV9hc7ZJh2g95F3eVDzmPajnxvejjP/cGOX/QKEG9H66HFBh7LQHEMRbjgJB4iKJ5lAkJA5oJAcTQ1kDrWWTsYGaWDPHieIfIAKkyDXzD9D926/ZDjC74Me/Y/u4OHmeQDHufJ/ltu6W8aY6gJUC1LaJ0en6fs96QdSaSP61vXtR1w1dOxDjnqfChvy1j/AoIV8H9Sb8qSKFQh%2BH%2B9A2x9x0oPNee8x79UOOpVCwAEBQBaJfQwihnTeE7t/dAEgl5QJAJg10sCSEb3HsA7eGCsE4KpAQlYFpaQMN7v3EhQ8XDkLHgAMi3pDLQMMP4FE4bQsGY4JDDV%2BNYPBLDl4wXYWQ2hPC%2BGGA8IIzcBQC5FHQOQpAB9mHTjPooXoBokA0OwdfBhqwu42jJI/KS8RX7ISsUI7Ruj1ISI6tIgxtp7HP0cUA8RkiiCuI8csaxMjhxsKwfEMJKxAmUhAYaQYHjgk2KifImJqSvEJKSVoq0zQogYiIQokR2CeElwEYglxyS76FMgdE0hZSKHcJLqomG1Tgl%2BhQSZYQ%2BJ5TCF0PEBKIAaiaAGCAFAzoJkVhihLQZuBhl8CQAAKzGQMFZKAWQbNmUgHIjMJaDBYjgYQ8QABEABSHwSAznHBLiyEeIAywrPURLfSxy%2BCnLOQAHTAGc1x%2BlmLnWwF835/zal8VaIJa%2Bhp9JAA)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3).

Also see [is there an inverse instruction to the movemask instruction in intel avx2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488675/is-there-an-inverse-instruction-to-the-movemask-instruction-in-intel-avx2) for other element sizes.

Comment: Could you give some idea on how you'd do it with AVX2? Thanks!

Comment: @alecco, I updated my answer showing how to do this with AVX2.  I tested it as well.

Comment: You're a star! Thanks a lot. Wish I could give you more upvotes.

Comment: If you want the resulting bytes to be 0 or -1 (so each bit of the mask expands to all bits of the vector byte), you need one more step.  After the shuffle, use `andn` instead of `and` (inverting `y`).  Then use a `_mm256_cmpeq_epi8` against a vector of all-zeros to invert again.

Comment: Also, I'd write mask2a as `_mm256_set1_epi64x(0x80'40'20'10'08'04'02'01)`.  (The C++14 `'` separators for readability are totally optional.)  To make it easy to select 128 vs. 256, you can use a `_mm_set1_epi64x()` and then the AVX2 version can use `_mm256_set_m128i(same,same)`.  It all optimizes away at compile time.

Comment: For mask1, I'd highly recommend using `_mm_set` rather than a load.  You absolutely don't want your function to compile into scalar immediate stores to the stack, and then a vector load!  Using `_mm_set` for constants allows sharing of the constant between multiple uses, exactly like string literal merging (probably even using the same compiler logic).  I don't see a nice way to write it more compactly, though, except with a CPP macro to repeat it's argument 8 times.

Comment: @PeterCordes, that's why I said " If you plan to do this several times you should probably define the masks outside of the main loop."

Comment: @PeterCordes, BTW, feel free to edit my answer with your suggestion but I prefer that you append your solution and not change what I have written.  Just a horizontal marker and write after that if you like.

Comment: @Zboson: I wasn't worried about it being hoisted or not, I was saying that it will waste instructions copying the data onto the stack, instead of just loading from a static constant.  Look at the asm from your version converted to a function taking an `int` arg, but still printing: https://godbolt.org/g/HfYeMd.  Note the `vmovdqa YMMWORD PTR [rbp-144], ymm0`.  It's storing the constant it just loaded from `.LC0`.  You can get rid of this with `static const char []`, but that still defeats constant-pool merging if this function was inlined into multiple files.  **Just use `_mm_set`**

Comment: There's [a duplicate of this that has the same the strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21622212/how-to-perform-the-inverse-of-mm256-movemask-epi8-vpmovmskb).  (Also suggesting an OR with a mask that has one bit *unset* and `vpcmpeqb` against `set1(0xFF)`, but an all-zeros vector is slightly cheaper to than all-ones)  Not sure if I should close it.  I was looking for a non-AVX version to link.  I guess this has a non-AVX2 version at least.

Comment: Do you HAVE to do it with assembly/intrinsics, or can you do it portably?

Comment: @PeterCordes: I think in `get 0 or -1` you can get away without `_mm256_setzero_si256` - by comparing with the `and` mask. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/LBAz_a

Comment: That's correct, that's a missed optimization here.  According to https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36491672/revisions (my answer on a duplicate of this), I didn't think of that until revision #6 in 2017, long after my last edit to this question.