# Intel intrinsics: vector comparison result to array of bool conversion

Tags: c, x86, boolean, sse, intrinsics

I have several functions used to compare floating-point math vectors that fill an array of booleans (with result of each comparison).
Currently, i am comparing them element-by-element, however i would like to use SIMD operations to optimize it.

The issue is, however, that intel intrinsics such as `_mm_cmpeq_ps` return a mask where every element is 32-bit. I am a little lost on how to convert the comparison mask to an array of booleans (guaranteed to be 8-bit).

I could shuffle every element of the SIMD vector, then extract the low elements, but i dont think that would provide an efficiency boost over manual element-by-element comparison.

Is there a way to cast the vector compare mask to a boolean array?

Comment: What do you want to do with the boolean array afterwards? In most cases it is much more efficient to directly use the mask for some follow-up operation(s).

Comment: @PeterCordes Sadly i cannot use the bitmask directly, i need an array of 8-bit booleans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bitmap is a more efficient way to store it, if you can have the rest of your program use that.  (e.g. via [Fastest way to unpack 32 bits to a 32 byte SIMD vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225786/fastest-way-to-unpack-32-bits-to-a-32-byte-simd-vector) or [is there an inverse instruction to the movemask instruction in intel avx2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488675/is-there-an-inverse-instruction-to-the-movemask-instruction-in-intel-avx2) if you want to use it with other vectors).

Or if you can cache-block it and use at most a couple KiB of mask vectors, you could just store the compare results directly for reuse without packing them down.  (In an array of `alignas(16) int32_t masks[]`, in case you want to access from scalar code).  But only if you can do it with a small footprint in L1d.  Or much better, use it on the fly as a mask for another vector operation so you're not storing/reloading mask data.

---

#### `packssdw`/`packsswb` dword compare results down to bytes

You're correct, if you don't want your elements packed down to single bits, don't use `_mm_movemask_ps` or `epi8`.  Instead, **use vector pack instructions**.  `cmpps` produces elements of all-zero / all-one bits, i.e. integer 0 (false) or -1 (true).

Signed integer pack instructions preserve 0 / -1 values, because both are in range for `int8_t`<sup>1</sup>.

To keep the compiler happy, you need `_mm_castps_si128` to reinterpret a `__m128` as a `__m128i`.

This works most efficiently packing 4 vectors of 4 float compare results each  down to one vector of 16 separate bytes.  (Or with AVX2, 4 vecs of 8 floats down to 1 vec of 32 bytes, requiring an extra permute at the end because `_mm256_packs_epi32` and so on operate in-lane, two separate 16-byte pack operations.  Probably a `_mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32` `vpermd` with a vector constant as the control operand)

```
// or  bool *result  if you keep the abs value (_mm_abs_epi8) for 0 / 1 output
void cmp(int8_t *result, const float *a)
{
  __m128 cmp0 = _mm_cmp_ps(...);  // produces integer 0 or -1 elements
  __m128 cmp1 = _mm_cmp_ps(...);
  __m128 cmp2 = _mm_cmp_ps(...);
  __m128 cmp3 = _mm_cmp_ps(...);

   // 2x 32-bit dword -> 16-bit word  with signed saturation - packssdw
  __m128i lo_words = _mm_packs_epi32(_mm_castps_si128(cmp0), _mm_castps_si128(cmp1));
  __m128i hi_words  = _mm_packs_epi32(_mm_castps_si128(cmp2), _mm_castps_si128(cmp3));

  __m128i cmp_bytes = _mm_packs_epi16(lo_words, hi_words);  // packsswb: 0 / -1

 // if necessary create 0 / 1 bools.  If not, just store cmp_bytes
  cmp_bytes = _mm_abs_epi8(cmp_bytes);                        // SSSE3
  //cmp_bytes = _mm_and_si128(cmp_bytes, _mm_set1_epi8(1));   // SSE2

  _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)result, cmp_bytes); 
}
```

Getting a 0/1 instead of 0/-1 takes a `_mm_and_si128` or SSSE3 `_mm_abs_epi8`, if you truly need `bool` instead of a zero/non-zero `uint8_t[]` or `int8_t[]`.

If you only have a single vector of float, you'd want SSSE3 `_mm_shuffle_epi8` (`pshufb`) to grab 1 byte from each dword, for `_mm_storeu_si32` (beware it was broken in early GCC11 versions, and wasn't even supported before then.  But now it is supported as a strict-aliasing-safe unaligned store.  Otherwise use `_mm_cvtsi128_si32` to int, and `memcpy` that to an array of `bool`.)

##### Footnote 1: signed pack instructions are the only good choice

All pack instructions before [AVX-512F `vpmovdb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpmovdb:vpmovsdb:vpmovusdb) / `vpmovusdb` do saturation (not truncation), and treat their inputs as signed.  This makes unsigned-pack instructions useless; we'd need to mask both inputs first or they'd saturate `-1` to `0`, not `0xffff` to `0xff`.

`punpcklwd` / `punpckhwd` can interleave 16-bit words from two registers, but only from the low or high half of those registers.  So not a great building-block.

Truncation would also work, but there's only SSSE3 `pshufb`, no 2-register shuffles as useful as the `pack..` instructions until AVX-512.  `vpblendw` could interleave halves of dwords in two different input registers)

Even with AVX-512, `vpmovdb` only has one input register, vs. `vpack...` instructions that produce a full-width output with elements from two full-width inputs.  (In 16-byte lanes separately, so you'd still need a `vpermd` at the end to put your 4-byte chunks that came from lanes of 4 floats into the right order).

Of course, AVX-512 using 512-bit vector width can only compare-into-mask.  This is fantastic for storing a bitmap, just `vcmpps k1, zmm0, [rsi]` / `kmov [rdi], k1`.  But for storing a bool array, probably you'd want to `kunpck` to concatenate compare results, with 2x `kunpckwd` to combine 16-bit to 32-bit masks, then `kunpckdq` to make a single 64-bit mask from 64 float compare results.  Then use that with a zero-masked `vmovdqu8 zmm0{k1}{z}, zmm1` and store that to memory.  (A memory destination only allows merge-masking, not zero-masking.)

AVX-512 could still be potentially useful with only 256-bit registers (to avoid turbo penalties and so on), although `vpermt2w` / `vpermt2b` aren't single-uop even on Ice Lake.

---

### Compiler auto-vectorization of scalar source is sub-optimal

Compilers *do* auto-vectorize (https://godbolt.org/z/3o58W919Y), but do a rather poor job.  Still very likely faster than scalar, especially with AVX2 available.

clang packs each vector down separately, for 4-byte stores.  But the individual packing is decently efficient.  With AVX2, it jumps through some extra hoops, vextractf128 and then packing 8 dwords down to 8 bytes, before shuffling that together with another 8 bools and then vinserti128 with another 16.  So it's eventually storing 32 bytes at a time of bools, but takes a *lot* of shuffles to get there.

Per YMM store, clang `-march=haswell` does 4 vextract, 8 packs, 2 vinsert, 1 vpunpcklqdq, 1 vpermq for a total of 16 shuffles, one shuffle per 2 bytes of output.  My version does 3 shuffles per 16 bytes of output, or with AVX2, 4 per 32 bytes if you widen everything to `__m256i` / `_mm256...` and add a final shuffle to fix up for lane-crossing.  (Plus 4x `vcmpps` and 1x `vpabsb` to flip -1 to +1.)

GCC uses unsigned pack instructions like [`packusdw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/packusdw) as the first step, doing `pand` instructions on each input to each pack instruction.  And also unnecessary one between the two steps because it's I think emulating unsigned->unsigned packing in terms of SSE4.1 `packusdw` / SSE2 `packuswb` signed->unsigned packs.  Even if it's stuck on using unsigned packing, it would be a lot less bad to just mask (or `pabsd`) the value to 0 or 1 so no further masking is needed before or after 2 packing steps.

(SSE2 `packssdw` preserves -1 or 0 just fine, without even saturating.  Seems GCC isn't keeping track of the limited value-range of compare results, so doesn't realize it can let the pack instructions just work.)

And without SSE4.1, GCC does even worse.  With only SSSE3 it uses some `pshufb` and `por` instructions, to feed 2x`pand`/SSE2 `packuswb`.

With word->byte pack instructions all treating their inputs as signed, it makes some sense that Intel omitted `packusdw` 32 -> 16-bit pack until SSE4.1, since the normal first step for packing dwords to bytes is `packssdw`, even if you eventually want to clamp signed integers to a 0..255 range.

Comment: I agree regarding signed saturation, but regarding "Unsigned packs would also saturate 0xFFFFFFFF to 0xFFFF": Are there SSE instructions which do unsigned->unsigned packs? `packusdw` packs `int32_t` to `uint16_t`, i.e. `0xFFFFFFFF = -1 --> 0x0000`

Comment: @chtz: Oh right, I got that right in my head earlier, but then got it wrong again while rushing to finish this answer before going out.  No, there aren't instructions which do unsigned->unsigned saturated packing, until [AVX-512F `vpmovusdb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpmovdb:vpmovsdb:vpmovusdb).  You're correct, `packusdw` would saturate `-1` to `0`.