# Convert 16 bit mask (__mmask16) to __m128i control byte mask on KNL (Xeon Phi 7210)

Tags: xeon-phi, avx512

I wish to performance a conversion between **__mmask16** and **__m128i**. However, as posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32247779/6889542

```
/* convert 16 bit mask to __m128i control byte mask */
_mm_maskz_broadcastb_epi8((__mmask16)mask,_mm_set1_epi32(~0))
```

**_mm_maskz_broadcastb_epi8** and anything similar to it are not available on KNL yet. The lack of **AVX512BW** on **KNL** (Xeon Phi 7210) is really becoming a headache for me.

The origin of the problem is that I wish to take advantage of

```
_mm_maskmoveu_si128 (__m128i a, __m128i mask, char* mem_addr)
```

while using

```
__mmask16 len2mask[] = { 0x0000, 0x0001, 0x0003, 0x0007,
                         0x000F, 0x001F, 0x003F, 0x007F,
                         0x00FF, 0x01FF, 0x03FF, 0x07FF,
                         0x0FFF, 0x1FFF, 0x3FFF, 0x7FFF,
                         0xFFFF };
```

Comment: Might be a bit late but I'd suggest to simply precompute a `__m128i len2maskvector` table like your `__mmask16 len2mask` table and directly fetch the vector you want. That saves an instruction at the cost of 224 additional bytes in cache. If you need to do it from a mask: `kmov, popcnt (or lzcnt), loada`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are actually intend to do generate something like:

```
__m128i mask = _mm_maskz_broadcastb_epi8(len2mask[length],_mm_set1_epi32(~0))
```

Why not just:

```
void foo(int length, char* mem_addr, const __m128i a)
{
    __m128i count = _mm_set_epi8(15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0);
    __m128i mask = _mm_cmpgt_epi8(_mm_set1_epi8(length), count);
    _mm_maskmoveu_si128 (a, mask, mem_addr);
}
```

[Godbolt demonstration](https://godbolt.org/g/ZqV2wV).

Comment: `_mm_maskmoveu_si128` is usually bad for performance (SSE2 `maskmovdqu` has NT store semantics).  On KNL where you don't have AVX512BW, a masked store of 16 bytes can be done with AVX-512F `vpmovdb`, aka `_mm512_mask_cvtepi32_storeu_epi8`, truncating a vector of 32-bit integers down to effectively a `__m128i`.  (Widening conversions like `_mm512_cvtepu8_epi32` (`vpmovzxbd`) are also available.)

Answer (score 1):

`_mm_maskmoveu_si128` is usually bad for performance.  SSE2 `maskmovdqu` has NT store semantics, so a mask that isn't all-ones will produce a non-full-line NT store.

On KNL where you don't have AVX512BW, **a masked store of 16 bytes can be done with AVX-512F [`vpmovdb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpmovdb:vpmovsdb:vpmovusdb), aka `_mm512_mask_cvtepi32_storeu_epi8`**, truncating a vector of 32-bit integers down to effectively a `__m128i`, so per-element masking gives you byte-masking for the cacheable cache.

Widening conversions like `_mm512_cvtepu8_epi32` (`vpmovzxbd`) are also available, if it's more convenient to have your data as a `__m128i` of 16x 8-bit integers instead of using an `__m512i` of 16x 32-bit integers in the first place.

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static inline
void masked_16byte_store(void *dst, __mmask16 msk, __m128i src)
{
#ifdef __AVX512BW__
    _mm_mask_storeu_epi8(dst, msk, src);
#else
    __m512i v512 = _mm512_cvtepu8_epi32(src);       // ideally work with 32-bit elements in the first place to skip this.
    _mm512_mask_cvtepi32_storeu_epi8(dst, msk, v512);
    // fun fact: GCC optimizes this to vmovdqu8 if available, but clang, ICC, and MSVC don't
#endif
}

void store_first_n_bytes(void *dst, int len, __m128i src)
{
   // len=0  => mask=0000
   // len=1  => mask=0001
   // len=16 => mask=FFFF

    //__mmask16 msk = _cvtu32_mask16(0xFFFFu >> (16-len));
    //__mmask16 msk = _cvtu32_mask16(_rotl(0xFFFFu<<16, len));  // rotate n  set bits into the bottom.  But variable-count rotates are 3 or 2 uops on Intel
    __mmask16 msk = _cvtu32_mask16((1U<<len) - 1);   // int is 32 bits so even 1<<16 doesn't overflow
    masked_16byte_store(dst, msk, src);
}
```

In your case, you don't need a lookup table for length->mask either, just use a bithack.  It compiles to a couple instructions; *possibly* there'd be some advantage to `kmov` from a lookup table<sup>1</sup>, if it always hits in cache and the front-end is a bottleneck (which [Agner Fog](https://agner.org/optimize/) says is common on KNL.)  `_cvtu32_mask16` to convert from `unsigned` to `__mmask16` is not necessary in practice; on the major implementations `__mmask16` is just `unsigned short` so implicit conversion works.

This compiles nicely with GCC, clang, and ICC ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBmAOykAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CQSHhLFEx8baY9vkMQgRMxASZPn5cFVXptfUEhWGR0XoKdQ1N2a2DXT3FpRIAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMzByN5YANQma254LCzBBMTBAHQI%2B9gmGgCC65vbmHsHg/iCVzd3jw/jjmQO2CtGCmF%2BADdUHh0DsWEwFABrTDoAD6XAAbBEAJ4ETCowYkTAQKEwnYAKnQg1IO1RqOOCMRmLhSJpdJYXDMAA48DsFEsZr8THErA8nlQsFRaaj7gA1AAaAFZORYAOp0347LW0470xkEojETBeVGYRJ4LkQKkEGksVl8gX7UWPMxrSpKTXa9nKsy8iE%2Bt4AER1LB9qOQELxiS8XNN5rWZgg/OQgrWFm1GYA9JngVgxLRsTsAO4kRHFwgIHYJgC0EUIO0qmDYggUwIYOwICFeNGIgx2iQMyw7qD5iLwiQ7CDwCgunq19NDnL1SPDkbNeATBqJJvXluttvt/s5qedWZzVC87aoTAcIB2AHE3G4dqhEo4TgAvTCtzvT4c7CEWFQCF0AARxjYEpSYCEmDoJgInoGkIi8Agdi2QxgB2dBUG/BgwA4AghVdVw8CoIU4kDIUHlJWFCSNVEe0GVEGFRHE8QUEloVhSlqTbVD6AYNl6U5HkHRTcjTy1bMdgE/ZAw0LU5JuOFGTkjR1I0OdpNktZAy4RTdOU%2BEkTU9SuC0nMdL0jEgyM1TdIAMSchyqPuM92WMpkbLtMs5NpCMCC8TdPMxCANFUZyHK8N5bjWbAdggTFqwEmYTznHZsw8xlmR8oN/MjIKzGXLyIFRYhUAIWgwoi5yvH2Nx6sxGkUpPKSc3Kuo8R2ds%2BUwVC6wIVtThHTtXgiCqiBYC4tVleo8Hg%2BhqzQS9UI6ph2J2epXjWF9iB2Mwdi8V9WwEHYAElBEqdKsqRHKkTy1dAuC7KMSgLg5Hq%2BqUp2asdi4Vq2r44FWwTHYBtbBQR0wCFGD%2Bz6DmZbDcPw1DgOiKhaFQIt0s8lF0SxXF8To4l9xZREaWTNKxQo34ODmWhOEVXg/A4LRSFQTgGssaw%2BQWJZXnWHhSAITQ6bmREQDWSQLi5DENEVRU4jWDRJFdDFJASBmOEkXgWAkdTSBZtmOY4XgFBADRhdFuY4FgGBEBQVAWHNegyAoCA0Gduh%2BmATlWhoWg8V7SgIlF0g62YYhsU4IXPebAgAHkGALMOsHhIxxFZ3h8CNBw8Bh82s9ITBVEwZAUJWIXTkqMPQQiYh6mxDwsDDs4jhjum%2BAMYAFFlPBMCLBPEkYDuZEEEQxHYKQx/kJQ1DD3Q1n0DCUGsax9DwCJzcgOZX2qQvqwTnafvhJZrl0xFk7Nxs8%2BcCBXBGFpi4YdBJj6GJWlyNIBEfnIUm/hgb8Sj9DGDfaonRhieGaAMMBHQhjdDBFMEBth4G/zGPAoB0x/rzEWMsPQZxMCV07lrJmhsw4m1ULLas6sdjAGQECTkFx9IQC5lYSwNJcCEBIHsV0rQdgeC9q7Hhaw1gzF4CLLOqVSBdiYFgGIEBxaSy4DLDQGIuAaAAJxrAxGYSQyszCqP0JwHWpA9aKjMBcOIGiNZxDiOrLgtiuRcgSEbXgJszYWytpI0gtsHaexdtEcglB/HexiOhIwUgDYByDubCAoci4R0bqPOOjBE7J2jkXNOGFM5sxzmXRwBcw4lzLhXUe1ctZszrg3KOzcVhszbnrbgncMZMB7n3AeQ8R5NJnhPcQ09%2BCCEUCodQRddDSAMEYVe3N2F123go9mb50gHyPlqasp9kDn0DEibEBhkTVmgqoH0192h3wflA0Yz9X6IPfn/PI6Q0FJH/tUTByC7D5LgV0B5bzb41Awdc4BH8UGfPOU/cYDQXkfzmJDXBU9hZGiIfTRmzNyGcEoRiahkg0ITMwlIC4Gg8UJVYevHYnDDTCL4QIgJe11iSDEV4rQUitYmL1hrC4BjzFmFdIqLknKuBcCXq49mnAPGWwkQyxRaxlFclUeorROi9EaAMRiIxHA1jIqLu4%2BlndfE6qQCE12QSPZOypSAX2Zh/Z0BiSHMOiSo7JKdvHJOKdMlNmyXU7OeBc4FO/EU0u5c8RlMuhU3gVTG61NbucRpPA5gtLaf3Qew8WZCwGcIUQfTpApqGfPUZsRl6TNMNMmwsz4C70WQIZZx81n1A2XJbZuzMD7IhIczkxz3mnJfg8wI/ysGPLuT/EFtyAEQpgSc35wKsigtgQICBCCig3PQeO6BC7wXdpAVCvmeDWgEIRSq0hgqKFUJoXQhhFjmFEvYSS/AZLBY0kpaE4RZg6VirFtIzAsj%2BjzIliIi4Ijf1/v/Sq5lIBzEXHVpIVWGJtHcg0RiDELiUWm1sJ459Nt7YQD1ca0Jhr9X9DwPQgx5rFSW2idEWJ8S2a2oybHB1qSnUZNya6jO7rSB5LzoUouxT/VEPIEG2um9qlNwwMxhpHcY3d17vGzpSbeApt6VPDNsgs0jLZroVo2KplsKLZvOZpb96cEPpW9Zmy61MD2Qco5bQ21%2BHvh2gdrQu1zoBYO6oDyv7PNXYC754DUF2csz8mdw7l2NF82C2dvQnPYOhfzfB8LRO7vVcbVFh7MV4aBAR5RioCUsLXhe0l3Cb38Mw0IwWT7rZzBkXIygiLta6xAKytYCtFbaLWHEdRv6yEauFUh0VZXSBfrWD%2B/9Q2REqrVR1xLiGUPVbMAltxXWpukBhr2dIdWgA%3D)), including for Skylake-avx512 (with AVX512BW):

```
 # GCC 12 -O3 -march=knl
store_first_n_bytes(void*, int, long long __vector(2)):
        vpmovzxbd       zmm0, xmm0
        mov     eax, -1
        shlx    eax, eax, esi
        not     eax
        kmovw   k1, eax
        vpmovdb XMMWORD PTR [rdi]{k1}, zmm0
        ret
```

```
 # ICC2021 -O3 -march=skylake-avx512   compiles the source more literally
store_first_n_bytes(void*, int, __m128i):
        mov       eax, 1                                        #24.21
        shlx      edx, eax, esi                                 #24.21
        dec       edx                                           #24.21
        kmovw     k1, edx                                       #8.5
        vmovdqu8  XMMWORD PTR [rdi]{k1}, xmm0                   #8.5
        ret                                                     #26.1
```

Or with `-march=knl`, ICC uses `add eax,-1`.  And of course `vpmovzxbd` / `vpmovdb`.  It uses ZMM16 as a temporary, perhaps because on non-KNL that would avoid needing a vzeroupper.  KNL doesn't ever need vzeroupper, and should avoid it because it's slow.

MSVC `-O2 -arch:AVX512` uses basically the same asm as ICC.  Using that compiler option defines `__AVX512BW__`, so I wouldn't recommend using MSVC to build for KNL.

Even better would be `xor eax,eax` / `bts eax, esi` (create 1<<len) / `dec eax`, but compilers often fail to use BTS which is single-uop  with a register destination on Intel CPUs.  (https://uops.info/).  The xor-zeroing is as cheap as a NOP on Sandybridge-family CPUs, and still fewer instruction bytes on others.  Smaller machine-code size should help KNL's weak front-end.

---

#### `kmov k, mem` costs on Xeon Phi vs. mainstream CPUs

According to Agner Fog's instruction tables, Xeon Phi (Knight's Landing) has `kmovw k,m` as a single uop with 2/clock throughput.  So a table lookup actually can save uops vs. a bithack.

But Skylake-server, Ice Lake, and Alder Lake (proxy for Sapphire Rapids) all run it as 3 uops for the front-end, 2 for the back-end (on ports p23 + p5).  Basically like a `mov` to a temporary general-purpose register plus a `kmov k, r`.  (https://uops.info/)

So a table lookup costs at least 3 front-end uops on mainstream CPUs, including a port 5 uop (like the `kmovw  k1, edx`).  And that's if the table is in static storage in a non-PIE executable, and `len` is already zero-extended to 64-bit.  So you can use a non-RIP-relative addressing mode like `kmovw k1, [LUT + rsi*2]`.  If you need a RIP-relative LEA in there for position-independent code, you're break-even with the bithack for front-end uops.  (Most Linux distros configure GCC with `-fPIE -pie` on by default, so would `lea rcx, [rip + LUT]` / `kmovw k1, [rcx + rsi*2]`)

---

**Without AVX-512, cacheable masked stores only allow 32-bit or 64-bit element size**, [`vmaskmovps/pd`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vmaskmov) and [`vpmaskmovd/q`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpmaskmov), `_mm_maskstore_epi32` and so on.  They're rather slow on AMD at least Zen 3 and earlier (up to 42 uops,  12 cycle throughput for 256-bit store with 8x 32-bit elements), since masked stores require special hardware support even when fault suppression isn't required.  Loads are easier; the hardware can just do a normal load and zero some elements after the fact.